# Any examples on using spark_read_csv correctly?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

when I run this:

```
terrorism <- spark_read_csv(sc, name = "terrorism", path = “\home\osboxes\Desktop\globalterrorismdb_0718dist.csv”)
```

I get this error:

> Error: unexpected input in "terrorism <- spark_read_csv(sc, name = "terrorism", path = �".

Please any ideas to debug this?

Comment: is this mac or windows? either way, check your path name, and maybe try using `/` (forward slash) not `\` (backslash)

Comment: why are you getting this symbol  �". ?? in the error message? try to read the file using the read file api in R, and print few lines . then use read_csv

Answer (score 0):

Your second pair of quotes looks weird; first pair looks fine.  This si the standard way of redaing a CSV in the Spark world.

```
val peopleDFCsv = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("sep", ";")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("header", "true")
  .load("examples/src/main/resources/people.csv")
```